# SQL To Select Records based on different values of a single column

Tags: sql

Table

```
Que_id | question    | isPicture | cat_det_id

1        Where are U?   1             27

2        Hello          0             22

3        Hey            1             31

4        What is Dis?   1             27
.. .    . ........      ..           ....
...     ...........     .             ...
```

Given the table in the picture as sample, I want select different number records based on different values of cat_det_id.

For Instance to select 5 records that has cat_det_id of 27, 10 Records that has cat_det_id of 31 and 7 records that has cat_det_id of 22

and these records will be presented as a records set ordered by this same cat_det_id in ascending order.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want one row per cat_det_id in your result or do you want all listed?

Comment: I think you should take some SQL tutorials - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: For some reason i assumed you were using Mysql, but you don't say that your question neither on tags, if you are using other RDMS you'll have to cahnge the LIMIT part since it is specific to mysql, but the union and order by will still work.

---

You could do it with union

```
(SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE  cat_det_id = 27 LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE  cat_det_id = 31 LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE  cat_det_id = 22 LIMIT 7)
ORDER BY cat_det_id ASC
```